# Difference in json array structure in ruby and google maps output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been searching on SO regarding the differences in output of the json arrays but haven't got any results useful to my usecase for it . Here's my issue , I have been using Google maps to display shapes and then show the selected portion into another into another map .

The output that Google map shows of selected portion -

```
[{"type":"RECTANGLE","id":null,"geometry":[[32.33733004161649,50.90904235665221],[32.377641904110355,50.989036558312364]]}]
```

The output that i recieve while using the to_json method -

```
"[{\"id\":null,\"type\":\"RECTANGLE\",\"radius\":\"3513.3954239013615\",\"geometry\":\"[32.39126846779702, 50.91075897042174]\"}]"
```

How or what can i do , to make the output of both the methods same so that i can display the data in the format it's intended to . New to json encode and decoding in rails , any help is much appreciated .

## Update 1 - After Omitting the to_json call

```
[{"id"=>nil, "type"=>"CIRCLE", "radius"=>"3513.3954239013615", "geometry"=>"[32.39126846779702, 50.91075897042174]"}]
```

Still , the "=>" won't be understood by google maps

Comment: The latter seems to be double-json-encoded. Try to simply omit call to `to_json` in the second case.

Comment: @mudasobwa Updated the question , please check the same

Comment: Also the lat and long are passed as an array in output whereas ruby takes it in as a string .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s consider you have a following array of hashes in ruby:

```
a = [{
  "id"=>nil, 
  "type"=>"CIRCLE", 
  "radius"=>"3513.3954239013615", 
  "geometry"=>"[32.39126846779702, 50.91075897042174]"
}]
```

You now need to make it understandable by google map. Here we go:

```
result = a.map { |e| # will convert geometry to what G expects
  ll = JSON.parse e["geometry"]
  e["geometry"] = [ll]  # passing just a single variable
  # you are likely to calc those basing on your radius value
  e
}.map(&:to_json)
```

Now don’t be confused by output of ruby `p`, it shows escaped strings. To assure, everything goes OK:

```
result.each { |e| puts e }
#⇒ {
#   "id":null,
#   "type":"CIRCLE",
#   "radius":"3513.3954239013615",
#   "geometry":[
#       [32.39126846779702,50.91075897042174],
#       [32.39126846779702,50.91075897042174]
#   ]
# }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks , i had to define radius and all the others seperately and the code worked like a charm :)